# Receive Clickable Link from REST API

Tags: php, arrays

I'm creating a string variable, creating a function to convert that string variable into a hyperlink, using that newly created function to convert the string variable into a hyperlink, passing that hyperlink to a PHP array, then passing that PHP array to a REST API. Lastly, I'm expecting the REST API to display my submission as a clickable link inside an iframe, **however, the iframe is displaying the raw html version of the hyperlink instead.**

Here's how I'm trying to do all this:

Creating a string variable

```php
$profile_link = "https://www.example.com/profile/".$chat_username;
```

Creating a function to convert that string variable into a hyperlink

```php
function plain_url_to_link($string) {
  return preg_replace(
  '%(https?|ftp)://([-A-Z0-9./_*?&;=#]+)%i', 
  '<a target="blank" rel="nofollow" href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a>', $string);
}
```

Using that newly created function to convert the string variable into a hyperlink

```
$profile_link = plain_url_to_link($profile_link);
```

Passing that hyperlink to a PHP array

```php
$data = [
    'username' => "$chat_username",
    'description' => $profile_link
];
```

From here, I pass that PHP array to the REST API, and the the REST API displays the raw code instead of the clickable link in an iframe.

I suspect that either

1. The conversion function is not actually a viable method for the job or
2. I'm unable to produce a clickable link in the iframe via the API because this is a cross-domain operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for HTML to be parsed by your browser as HTML you must provide an appropriate `Content-type` HTTP header in the response. A content type of **text/plain** for example, will force the browser to treat the response as plain text and no parsing of HTML will occur. A content type of **text/html**, however, will force the browser to treat the response as HTML, requiring further parsing before it's displayed.

```
<?php
// This will not produce a clickable link
header("Content-type: text/plain");
?><a href="https://www.google.com/">google</a>
```

Here's how to get the browser to treat it as expected

```
<?php
// This will produce a clickable link
header("Content-type: text/html");
?><a href="https://www.google.com/">google</a>
```

Whether you do this in an iframe or not has no effect on the final result. The browser must get some hint as to the type of content the server is providing. My guess is that in a REST API it makes no sense to send a Content-type header of *text/html* and as such you're getting the results you're getting. REST API's typically aren't accessed via a Client UA (*Browser*).

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. My conclusion is that the owner of the REST API is going to make the decision on which content type to use, and if it's text/plain, then a clickable link isn't an option.